# The content of my page is located within the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, routes, navbar, stylus, emblem.js

The line that separates the content and the navbar stays below the content instead of in between. This happens with all of the pages that are routed to the main page that has the navbar. I've tried to add padding-top, relative positioning, margin-top etc. to the body but it stays within the navbar. It seems like they are on the same row but adding a .row to the navbar and to the content seems to do nothing since they are separate .emblem files.

This is the emblem with the navbar:

```
.display-options
    ul.nav.nav-tabs
        link-to "ediagnostic.entry" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.entry"
                | Entry
        link-to "ediagnostic.stations" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.stations"
                | Work Station
        link-to "ediagnostic.spur" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.spur"
                | Spur
        link-to "ediagnostic.exit" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.exit"
                | Exit
        link-to "ediagnostic.partqueue" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.partqueue"
                | Part Queue
        link-to "ediagnostic.maintenanceCall" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.maintenanceCall"
                | Maintenance Call
        link-to "ediagnostic.manual" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.manual"
                | Manual
        link-to "ediagnostic.alarmlog" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.alarmlog"
                | Alarmlog
        link-to "ediagnostic.itinterface" tagName="li" href="false"
            link-to "ediagnostic.itinterface"
                | IT Interface

        =outlet
```

When I try to throw anything like this into the emblem that routes to the navbar emblem, it just appears within the same row as navbar:

```
.row
    h1 hello
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `=outlet` line should be outdented to not be a child of `ul.nav.nav-tabs` anymore.